# How to add save button in a form magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9, fieldset, adminhtml

How can I add **save button** for each form and not one for all forms (as we have in magento by default)?
I want something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiRQg.jpg) or into the form.
I've tried this code

```
$fieldset->addField('yourfield', 'button', array(
'label' => Mage::helper('thorleif')->__('Button Labels'),
'value' => Mage::helper('thorleif')->__('Button Caption'),
'name'  => 'yourfield',
'style' => 'width:64px; height:21px;',
'class' => 'form-button',
'onclick' => "setLocation('{$url}')",
));
```

But I get a button without word like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK7ZB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that always the value in html source code goes empty. So I've read that you have to change `$form->setValues` in your file by `$form->addValues` and it will work.